# Unix shell: suppress/replace all characters in a character-range

Tags: bash, sed

With numbers it's easy:

```
sed "s/[0-9]/ /g" $source_file

Source line: Hello1Hello2Hello3Bye
Exit line: Hello Hello Hello Bye
```

But, let's say I need to rid of ASCII(128) through ASCII(255), what is a matching syntax?

Individual bytes.

Comment: `tr -d '\200-\377' < "$source_file"`?

Comment: Though knowing what encoding your input uses is needed for a good answer. Individual bytes? UTF-8? Etc.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
echo 'äöüÄÖÜß' | LC_ALL=C sed 's/[\d128-\d255]/ /g'
```

Comment: Worked with the addition of LC_ALL=C, otherwise was getting "Invalid collation character".

Comment: You can use POSIX sed too.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the character class with the 7th bit set. POSIX [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) are useful in this case.

You can use `perl` with the negated `ascii` character class:

```
perl -lpe 's/[^[:ascii:]]/ /g' file
```

If you want to use character classes based ordinal codes the syntax is this:

```
perl -lpe 's/[\x{7F}-\x{FF}]/ /g'
```

You need to use hex in [Perl character classes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass).